# Alignment of two equations

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment

How can i make that the units are right under the corresponding term?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left = 30mm, right = 30mm}    
\usepackage[it]{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{showframe} % just for demonstration of hfil vs hfill and centering...
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
\[
-E(s)I\frac{\partial^4 \vec{w}(s,t)}{\partial s^4} + \overline{m}(s) \frac{\partial^2 \vec{w}(s,t)}{\partial t^2}  + c(s) \frac{\partial \vec{w}(s,t)}{\partial t} = \widehat{m}\vec{a}(t)
\]
\[
[\frac{kgm^3}{s^2}][\frac{1}{m^3}] + [\frac{kg}{m}][\frac{m}{s^2}] + [\frac{kg}{ms}][\frac{m}{s}] = [\frac{kg}{m}][\frac{m}{s^2}]
\]  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make some that actually compiles. And perhaps you should make your example a lot more minimal, there are a lot of packages here that is not relevant for a question about equation alignment

Comment: Runaway argument?
{{document} 
! Paragraph ended before \end was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.131

Comment: as a side note, please learn to use `siunitx` to typeset units, there are rules for units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do it here by stacking the unit under each term.  EDITED to incorporate `siunitx` calls, invoked in customized form as `\mySI{<units>}`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Usepackages %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                 % Deutsche Tastatur / Umlaute
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                    % Erweiterte Deutsche Sprache (Umlaute, Sonderzeichen etc)
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}                 % Deutscher Schriftsatz, Silbentrennung, neue Deutsche          Rechtschreibung etc.
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{graphicx}                       % Für Einbindung von Grafiken
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}    % Verlinkt das Inhaltsverzeichnis ohne roten Rahmen

% Spezialpakete
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
% TikZ-Bibliotheken
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}


\usepackage{geometry}                       % Für Seitenränder
\geometry{left = 30mm, right = 30mm}    

\usepackage{scrpage2}                       % Für Kopf und Fußzeilen

\usepackage{listings}                       % Für Quellcode
\usepackage{mathcomp}                       % Für Matrizen
\usepackage{tabularx}                       % Für Tabellen
\usepackage{amsmath}                        % Befehle für Formellayout
\usepackage{amssymb}                        % Mathematische Sonderzeichen
\usepackage{amsthm}                         % Für Theoremstyle
\usepackage{floatflt}                       % Text um Bild
\usepackage[small, it]{caption}             % Caption von Bild ist it
\usepackage{cite}                           % Literaturverzeichnis
\usepackage{listings}                       % Für Quellcode

\usepackage{subfig}

%%% Für Definitionen %%%
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

%%% Für Sätze %%%
\theoremstyle{theorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Satz}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%% Kopf- und Fußzeile %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%\pagestyle{scrheadings}
%\clearscrheadings
%
%% Kopfzeile %
%\ihead{\leftmark}
%\automark{section}
%%\ohead{\includegraphics[trim = 0mm 0mm 0mm 20mm, height = 5mm]{./images/FAU.png}}
%\headsep=20mm  % Größe der Kopfzeile festlegen
%
%% Fußzeile %
%\cfoot{Gruppe: \\
%      Erdbebensicheres Bauen}
%\ifoot{\today}
%\ofoot{Seite \pagemark}
%\footskip=15mm % Größe der Fußzeile festlegen

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% For code listings %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Selbst eingefügt %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{xcolor,soul}        % highlighting
\usepackage{listings}           % listings print source code

% define colors for source code list
\definecolor{colKeys}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\definecolor{colIdentifier}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{colComments}{rgb}{0,1,0.3}
\definecolor{colString}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}

\lstset{language=Matlab,
   keywords={persistent,zeros},
   float=hbp,
   basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
   identifierstyle=\color{colIdentifier},
   keywordstyle=\color{blue},
   commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
   columns=flexible,
   tabsize=2,
   frame=single,
   numbers=left,
   extendedchars=true,
   showspaces=false,
   numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
   stepnumber=1,
   numbersep=10pt,
   showspaces=false,
   showstringspaces=false,
   breakautoindent=true}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%% Sonstige Commands etc %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%\linespread{1.2}
%\pagenumbering{Roman}

\newcommand{\correct}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\usepackage{stackengine,siunitx}
\sisetup{
  per-mode=fraction,
  fraction-function=\dfrac
}
\stackMath
\newcommand\mySI[1]{\Bigl[\SI{}{#1}\Bigr]}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{frame}{Formulierung des Modells}
\[
\def\stacktype{L}
\setstackgap{L}{2\baselineskip}
\stackunder{-E(s)}{\mySI{\kg \m\cubed \per \s\squared}}
\stackunder{I\dfrac{\partial^4 \vec{w}(s,t)}{\partial s^4}}{\mySI{\per \m\cubed}}
\stackunder{{}+{}}{+}
\stackunder{\overline{m}(s)}{\mySI{\kg\per\m}}
\stackunder{\dfrac{\partial^2 \vec{w}(s,t)}{\partial t^2}}{\mySI{\m\per\s\squared}}
\stackunder{{}+{}}{+}
\stackunder{c(s)}{\mySI{\kg\per\m\per\s}}
\stackunder{\dfrac{\partial \vec{w}(s,t)}{\partial t}}{\mySI{\m\per\s}}
\stackunder{{}={}}{=}
\stackunder{\widehat{m}}{\mySI{\kg\per\m}}
\stackunder{\vec{a}(t)}{\mySI{\m\per\s\squared}}
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you change `\dfrac` to `\tfrac` in the `\sisetup` call, then the units can be presented in compressed form:

[image]

Note that the baselineskip to the underset line is specified in the code `\setstackgap{L}{2\baselineskip}`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `siunitx` for the units; for the alignment, use an `array`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\sisetup{per-mode=fraction}
\begin{array}{
 >{\displaystyle}c
 >{\displaystyle}c
 *{3}{
   >{{}}c<{{}}
   >{\displaystyle}c
   >{\displaystyle}c
 }
}
-E(s)           & I\frac{\partial^4 \vec{w}(s,t)}{\partial s^4}
 & + &
\overline{m}(s) & \frac{\partial^2 \vec{w}(s,t)}{\partial t^2}
 & + &
c(s)            & \frac{\partial \vec{w}(s,t)}{\partial t}
 & = &
\widehat{m}     &\vec{a}(t)
\\[2ex]
\biggl[\si{\kilogram\cubed\per\second\squared}\biggr] &
  \biggl[\si{\per\meter\cubed}\biggr]
 & + &
\biggl[\si{\kilogram\per\meter}\biggr] &
  \biggl[\si{\meter\per\second\squared}\biggr]
 & + &
\biggl[\si{\kilogram\per\meter\per\second}\biggr] &
  \biggl[\si{\meter\per\second}\biggr]
 & = &
\biggl[\si{\kilogram\per\meter}\biggr] &
  \biggl[\si{\meter\per\second\squared}\biggr]
\end{array}
\]  
\end{document}
```

[image]